# Error like unable to load ace.dll32 while opening c# application into another pc

Tags: c#, visual-studio, advantage-database-server

**I want to connect my script with advantage data architect 11.10 database and display table in grid view. this is my below code**

```
    namespace serarchSys_ByDeshal
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            AdsConnection con = new AdsConnection(@"Data source=N:\Adjobsys\Dictionary\JobSys.add;");


            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string dd = "SELECT * from release ";
                AdsDataAdapter adapter = new AdsDataAdapter(dd, con);
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(table);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

                con.Close();


            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ads connections, but don't you have to .Open() before you can use it?

Comment: i have tried it already.but still not working

Comment: thank you so much Ken it works for me

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy your app to another machine, you have to also include the Advantage client libraries. See your Advantage install folder, in the Redistribute subfolder. Also see the Advantage help file, which tells you exactly which files you need to include and why. The ADS DLLs should be in the same folder as your application's executable or a folder on the Windows search path.